# How to find the probability of the most likely configuration in statistical mechanics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

> Consider a large number $N$ of distinguishable particles distributed
>   among $M$ boxes.
>
> We know that the total number of possible microstates is
>   $$\Omega=M^N$$  and that the number of microstates with a distribution
>   among the boxes given by the configuration $[n_1, n_2, ..., n_M]$ is
>   given by $$\frac{N!}{\prod_{j=1}^M (n_j)!}\tag{1}$$ The most likely
>   configuration corresponding to the particles distributed equally among
>   the $M$ boxes is trivially $$n_0=\frac{N}{M}\tag{2}$$ Now if we
>   let $\Omega_0$ denote the statistical weight of this configuration and
>   $p_0$ its probability.

How should I go about calculating $p_0$?

---

This is how I thought it should be done:

$$p_0=\frac{\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)}{\frac{N!} {\prod_{j=1}^M (n_j)!}}=\color{red}{\fbox{$\frac{N}{M}\frac{\prod_{j=1}^M (n_j)!}{N!}$}}$$

where all I did was divide $(2)$ by $(1)$ since by my logic the probability is simply *the most likely configuration* **divided by** *the total number of configurations*.

---

But apparently this is not the case and the correct answer is $$p_0=\frac{\Omega_0}{\Omega}=\frac{\frac{N!}{\Big(\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)!\Big)^M}}{M^N}=\color{#180}{\fbox{$\frac{N!}{\Big(\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)!\Big)^M M^N}$}}$$

Could someone please provide me with any hints or an explanation to justify why $$\color{#180}{p_0={\fbox{$\frac{N!}{\Big(\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)!\Big)^M M^N}$}}}$$ is the correct answer?

---

### EDIT:

I have already been given an answer by BLAZE but I feel that there is a *much* easier way of calculating $p_0$. The reason I say this is because the answer to the problem was just stated as

$$p_0=\frac{\Omega_0}{\Omega}=\frac{\frac{N!}{\Big(\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)!\Big)^M}}{M^N}={\fbox{$\frac{N!}{\Big(\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)!\Big)^M M^N}$}}$$ without any other working.

How does one arrive at this answer without writing down any intermediate steps?

Thanks.

Comment: related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/626624/226902

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the thing that is confusing you here is the location of the factorial function. So in this answer I will place it *inside* the brackets just to avoid confusion:

Lets consider the way you were trying to calculate $p_0$ by using

> $$\frac{N!}{\prod_{j=1}^M \large(n_j!)}\tag{1}$$

The probability $p_0$ must be equal to $$p_0=\frac{\Omega_0}{\Omega}=\frac{\frac{N!}{\prod_{j=1}^M \large(n_j!)}}{M^N}\tag{a}$$ as it is the ratio of no. of most likely configurations to *all* possible configurations (which is $M^N$).

Now simply replace $n_j$ with $$n_0=\frac{N}{M}$$ This is allowed since $n_j$ is just one of the configurations. But in our case all the $n_j$'s are the same and equal to $n_0$ since we are only interested in finding the probability of the *most likely* configuration.

So the infinite product just becomes $$\prod_{j=1}^M (n_j!)=\prod_{}^M (n_0!)=\prod_{}^M \left[\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)!\right]=\left[\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)!\right]^M\tag{b}$$ 
where the last equality can be thought of as the fact that we have $M$ lots of $$\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)!$$ or explicitly: 
$$\left[\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)!\right]^M=\overbrace{\left[\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)!\right]\cdot\left[\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)!\right]\cdot\left[\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)!\right]\cdot\left[\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)!\right]\cdots}^{\Large\text{M times}}$$

Substitute $(\mathrm{b})$ into $(\mathrm{a})$ and the result $${\fbox{$p_0=\frac{N!}{\Big(\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)!\Big)^M M^N}$}}$$ immediately follows.

Answer (score 2):

Here we use the [Multinomial Coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) 
formula since we have $M$ boxes to place $N$ particles in.

Suppose that we label the $M$ boxes as $M_1,M_2,...,M_{n-1},M_n$ where the $M$ boxes have been split **equally** amongst the particles as $\dfrac{N}{M}$ such that $M_1=M_2=M_{n-1}=M_n$ and also $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n M_i=M$.

What we are interested in for this purpose is the $\dfrac{N}{M_i}$ factors which will become clear when you consider the following:

$$\binom{N}{\frac{N}{M_1},\frac{N}{M_2},\frac{N}{M_{n-1}},...,\frac{N}{M_n}}=
\binom{N}{\frac{N}{M_1}}\binom{N-\frac{N}{M_1}}{\frac{N}{M_2}}\binom{N-\frac{N}{M_2}}{\frac{N}{M_{n-1}}}\cdots\binom{N-\frac{N}{M_{n-1}}}{\frac{N}{M_n}}=
\frac{N!}{(N-\frac{N}{M_1})!\cdot \frac{N}{M_1}!}\cdot\frac{(N-\frac{N}{M_1})!}{(N-\frac{N}{M_2})!\cdot \frac{N}{M_2}!}\cdot\frac{(N-\frac{N}{M_2})!}{(N-\frac{N}{M_{n-1}})!\cdot \frac{N}{M_{n-1}}!}\cdots\frac{(N-\frac{N}{M_{n-1}})!}{(N-\frac{N}{M_n})!\cdot \frac{N}{M_n}!}=
\frac{N!}{\Big(\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)!\Big)^M}$$ where in the last line mass cancellation occurs and I have used the fact that all the $M_i=M$ and that there must be $M$ lots of $\dfrac{N}{M_i}$ since $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n M_i=M$ as mentioned previously.

So the statistical weight $\Omega_0$ of the *most likely* configuration is $$\Omega_0=\frac{N!}{\Big(\left(\frac{N}{M}\right)!\Big)^M}$$

But we already know that the statistical weight of the total number of configurations is $$\Omega=M^N$$ dividing $\Omega_0$ by $\Omega$ gives you the desired formula in green.

---

If you are struggling to follow the general formula for the multinomial coefficients then think about this problem that I have come across:

Consider a standard pack of $52$ playing cards. The cards are distributed into $4$ piles completely randomly by tossing a four-sided die for each card.
Calculate how many microstates there are corresponding to having $13$ cards in
each pile, i.e. the most-likely configuration.

\begin{align}\binom{52}{13,13,13,13}&=\binom{52}{13}\binom{39}{13}\binom{26}{13}\binom{13}{13}\\&=\frac{52!}{(52-13)!\cdot 13!}\cdot\frac{{(52-13)!}}{(39-13)!\cdot 13!}\cdot\frac{{(39-13)!}}{(26-13)!\cdot 13!}\cdot\frac{{(26-13)!}}{(13-13)!\cdot 13!}\\&=\frac{52!}{(13!)^4}\end{align}

Comment: There must be a simpler way of getting to the result, as the answer was given with virtually no intermediate steps. Can you help?

Comment: Actually, in the realm of physics, this method is pretty simple.